# copying one field to another but adding commas between words?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a field called title.

I have a second field called tagline.

The user will fill in the title manually, and I would need the tagline field to be a copy of the title field, but with commas between each word.

So, a user would put "red apples" in the title, then the tagline would be the same as the title but with commas between the words.

Title = red apples 
tagline = red, apples

Can somebody talk me through the code to do this please?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a free developer?

Comment: where do u want to display tagline? or do u want to store it in the database ?

Comment: Are you looking for a PHP solution or a Javascript solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$title = 'red apples '; 
$title= trim($title); //make sure no space before or after the string, it would convert to comma
$tagline = str_replace(' ', ',', $title)
```

Comment: Add four spaces to format code. And use the preview-pane to review before submitting.

Answer (score 2):

```
var title = "red apples";
var tagline = title.split(" ").join(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/awrhe/)

```
<input id="title" type="text" value="Red Apples" />
<input id="tagline" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" value="do stuff" onClick="stuff()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.stuff = function(){
        title = document.getElementById("title");
        tagline = document.getElementById("tagline");
        tagline.value = title.value.split(" ").join(", ");
    }
</script>
```